# Trying to launch url in Edge with IE compatability mode using robotframe work python

Tags: python-2.7, internet-explorer, robotframework, microsoft-edge, ride

I'm Trying to launch url in Edge with IE compatibility mode using robotframe work python and I'm using below code but getting this error **AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'attach_to_edge_chrome'** . Can some please help on this

**code used:**

**Open Browser  url     ie  options=ignore_zoom_level=True;attach_to_edge_chrome=True; edge_executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"**

Comment: What version of edge? What OS? Starting June 15, 2022, Internet Explorer 11 will no longer be supported on certain versions of Windows 10.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have to be attached to Edge? You might find greater success in using Firefox

Comment: I test your code and it works well. Which version of `robotframework` and `SeleniumLibrary` are you using? Which version of IE WebDriver, Edge browser and Edge WebDriver are you using?

Comment: Im using these versions  @YuZhou         -------robot framework-4.1.3,
selenium-4.0.0,
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 4.5.0,
IEdriver 4.5.0,
Edge browser-106.0,

Comment: I use the latest version `robotframework 5.0.1` and `SeleniumLibrary 6.0.0`. Please update to the latest version and test again.

Comment: I have updated with latest versions, now the url is opening but only open browser is keep on running it is not going to the next step which is maximize window. But in chrome everything is working fine.Can u help on this @YuZhou

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Maximize Browser Window` to maximize the browser window. Please refer to the sample code below (you can change the path to your owns):

```
*** Settings ***
Library   SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${IEDriver}  E:/webdriver/IEDriverServer.exe

*** Test Cases ***
Example Test
    Open Browser  https://www.google.com/  ie  executable_path=${IEDriver}  options=ignore_zoom_level=True; attach_to_edge_chrome=True; edge_executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
    Maximize Browser Window
```

Robot Framework version: 5.0.1

SeleniumLibrary version: 6.0.0

Comment: im using what you have mentioned but only Open Browser is keep on running, it is not going to the next keyword :(

Comment: Is there any error? Please try to kill all Edge and IE process in Task Manager and test again. Besides, I met similar issue when I missed some spaces in the line of `Open Browser` code. Please check again if the spaces between the codes are right, especially there's a space between `options=ignore_zoom_level=True;` and `attach_to_edge_chrome=True;`

Comment: Open Browser    https://www.google.com/    ie    executable_path=${Iedriver}  options=ignore_zoom_level=True; attach_to_edge_chrome=True; edge_executable_path=${edgepath}
    Close Window ------------ not getting any error . Google URL is opening in edge IE mode and after that nothing is happening, it is not going to the next step in the code . And Im giving the proper spaces also.

Comment: I guess Complete page is not loading properly after long time im getting time out exception for page load.

Comment: It might be the reason. It's so strange it doesn't work in your environment. You can check my result, it works well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DgQI.gif. How about change to another url? And do you have another environment to test?

Comment: I'm trying to run script using RIDE, and it is not loading complete page .

Comment: TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for page to load.           getting this error after waiting 5:31 min

Comment: hi Yu Zhou, can you please let me know the version of edge and IE driver which you are using

Comment: At that time, I remember I use the same Edge and IE driver version as yours.